# How can I override javascript XHR prototype to send and receive data from a websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, overriding, dom-events

I'm trying to do something really weird / stupid, I'm trying to build a kind of a Websocket proxy for XHR requests.

Lets say that you have a component on the page that is constantly requesting resources by XHR (GET's) and this is the flow I want to achieve:

1. Intercept the XHR GET request (done);
2. Forward it through a Websocket (done);
3. The server takes the URL and params, makes the call to the remote endpoint and returns the data via Websocket back to the client (done);
4. Inject the response received by the Websocket back to the original XHR GET and finish it (not done)

So my trouble right now is not being able to "emulate" the finish of the XHR request with the response data from the Websocket, is there any event that can be triggered or a method?

Can someone please give me some ideas or solutions regarding this?

My current code:

```
XHR.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass) {
  const self = this;

  function getter() {
    console.log('get responseText');
    delete XHR.responseText;
    // var ret = XHR.responseText;
  }

  function setup() {
    Object.defineProperty(XHR, 'responseText', {
      get: getter,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
  setup();

  socket.emit('req', url);
  socket.on('reqr', data => {
    var event = new Event('loadend');
    setup();
    self.dispatchEvent(event, data);
    // return data;
  });
  // this._url = url;
  // open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
}
```

Comment: so, you want a list of events for XHR? [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget)

Comment: well, I already tried to dispatch the event "onloadend" manually but nothing happens.

`
var event = new Event('onloadend');
self.dispatchEvent(event);
`

Comment: well, the event is called `loadend` for a start - see the list of events on the left side of the documentation I linked to? see how they don't start with `on` :p

Comment: Yep, just corrected it, no luck i will attach my current code to the op.

Comment: why only loadend? what "events" does the current code listen to? readystatechange? load? error? abort? timeout? etc Really, it depends on what the XHR code is listening for

Comment: My question, is how can I pass the data when dispatching the event.

Comment: oh, I see ... but those events don't contain data in XHR ...

Comment: @joao I am interested in doing this too, did you finally figure out a solution for this ?